# Jsoup text extraction

Tags: xhtml, html-parsing, jsoup

Here is an extraction case which I would like to know if there is a native method in Jsoup or possibly any other HTML parser to do effectively. Suppose I have the following page from which I want to extract "StackOverFlow" and any nearby text which would form a proper sentence.

```
<html> <head><title>A test page </title></head> 
<body> 
<p> Not relevant 1. </p>
<p> Not relevant 2. 
<em> word1 word2 word3 <b> StackOverFlow </b> word4 word5 word6 </em>
</p>
</body>  
</html>
```

The text that should be extracted is : word1 word2 word3 StackOverFlow word4 word5 word6.
and not this: Not relevant 2. word1 word2 word3 StackOverFlow word4 word5 word6

i.e. is there a way of identifying sentence boundaries in Jsoup? One could think of some regular expressions but I wonder if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
doc.select("em").text();
```

Comment: thanks. This is just an example, it could be "em" or anything else. It might also be nested into a hierarchical structure.

Comment: If it in the any tag, it will work.  The main thing here - to select correctly tag with required text.

Comment: Yes, but my question is how to select correctly tag with required text? why not <b>? why em is the right tag and not P above it?

Comment: if you want to select tag with concrete text, you must use `:contains(text)`  selector. For example: `doc.select("em:contains(word1 word2 word3)").text();`

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use CSS JQuery alike selectors.
Please read also about "combinators" also, so you will control of from wich element your element must be child.

http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html